# Formik handling state with array of objects

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I'm newly using Formik library for forms and I ran into problem. I'm not sure how can I handle state with array of objects from inside the component. I know about `setValues` and `setFieldValue` methods.. also about `FieldArray` but my target is to add newZone into newZones array when I click on add button and I don't want to render it. I want to customize rendering and place it under accordion.

sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-haze-zdlw9?file=/src/App.js

Will I need all custom handlers? Will I need to use local state inside component and then use `setFieldValue` to set state? Or can I somehow use `FieldArray` in there without rendering?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using React-Bootstrap components instead Formik components, so you must manually assign `handleChange` and `value` props to every input component. You also have to call `setFieldValue()` when user clicks button **Add**.

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-leaf-tr3rv